# SQL Server Stored Procedure, selecting rows from multiple tables

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have a stored procedure that is pulling data from one table, now I have got the same data collected in a different table, as the IDs are different I cannot put all data from the second table into the first one.

So now I have to have two select statements in one stored procedure.

Although the corresponding data is same but the column names in both table are different.

For instance `BRIEF_TITLE` would be `briefTitle` in the second table.

How can I merge the data from two different tables into one?

The result is bonded to ASP.net grid view control.

Comment: Sounds like you should do a [UNION](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)

Comment: You are looking for the `union all` statement.

Comment: Can you use aliases to match the field names, then UNION the two statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments above state, you need something like this:

```
select BRIEF_TITLE from t1
union all
select briefTitle from t2
```

This will give you a column name of `BRIEF_TITLE`, but if you want something else, then add an alias to the first select

```
select BRIEF_TITLE as ShortTitle from t1
union all
select briefTitle from t2
```